normalization of an algebraic curve
I am trying to solve this exercise:

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial with distinct roots different from $0$. What is the normalization of the algebraic curve $y^2=x^2f(x)$?

My attempt:
We call the base field $k$ and we try the usual trick.
Consider the inclusion:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  R:=k[x,y]/(y^2-x^2f) &\hookrightarrow \tilde{R}:=k[x,\tilde{y}]\\\\
  x &\mapsto x\\\\
        y &\mapsto \tilde{y}:=\frac{y}{x}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Then $\tilde{y}^2-f=0$ So $\tilde{R}$ is integral over $R$. Moreover $\tilde{R}$ is a UFD so it is normal.
My questions

Is the proof correct?
I understand that choosing $f$ with distinct roots is important so that $y$ is not generated by $x$, but why do we require that roots are distinct from $0$?

Thank you.

(1) Not sure what you mean by that attempt but it doesn’t look correct.
The normalization is the curve given by (the Spec of) $ k[x,z]/(z^2 - f(x)) $. The normalization map sends a point $ (x,z) $ to $ (x,xz) $.
(2) I’m quite sure that this works even if $ 0 $ is a simple root of $ f $. The assumption that $ f(x) $ has distinct roots is used to guarantee that the normalization is indeed a normalization, i.e. it is smooth by the Jacobian criterion. If $ 0 $ is not a root of $ f $, it implies that the singularity at $ (0,0) $ is an ordinary double point and hence under the normalization map, it should have two preimages, as it indeed does. If $ 0 $ is a simple root of $ f $, then the curve has a cuspidal singularity at the origin and hence under the normalization map, it should have one preimage as it does, yet again.
*I’m assuming that the field is of char=0, or even complex numbers.

Could you please explain why if $0$ is not rooot of $f$ then $(0,0)$ is a double point? The equation should be $y^2-x^2f(x)=0$. I can believe it but I don't see why?

because analytically locally near x=0, f is non-vanishing hence f = g^2 for some locally non-vanishing g. Then the equation becomes (y-xg)(y+xg) = 0. If u = xg then u is a coordinate at x=0 again because g is locally non-vanishing. So locally in the right-coordinates, the equation is (y-u)(y+u) = 0, an ODP.

The above comment is the idea behind the normalization anyway: we just need to ‘find’ a global square root of f which is easy in algebraic geometry due to the ring construction.

Many thanks, it makes sense to me now!

the Unswer provided by @Cranium Clamp is excelent. However, I want to add some explicit computations to the whole problem.
Firstable, If we assume that $f(x)$ does not vanish in zero, $f(x)$ has the form
$f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_nx^n$, with $a_0\neq0$, and so the equation
$$y^2-x^2f(x)=y^2-(a_0x^2+a_1x^3+\dots+a_nx^{n+2}),$$
says that $(0,0)$ is nodal singularity, because the tangent at $(0,0)$ is just
$y^2-a_0x^2=0$ which splits in two different lines (assume that $k=\mathbb{C}$ for example). On the other side if $f(x)$  vanishs at zero then $f(x)=a_ix^i+\dots+a_nx^n$ for some $i\geq 1$, en so the tangent space at zero will be $y^2=0$, then the point $(0,0)$ is double point, and we need more than one blow-up to normalize the curve.
Now, in the case of the problem, i.e., $f(x)$ does not vanish at zero, we only need one blow-up. We can use the coordinates $x,u,v$, and $y$, and the relation $xv=yu$, in the affine chart $u=1$, we get
$$x^2v^2-x^2f(x)=x^2(v^2-f(x))=0,$$
the curve $x=0$ is the exceptional divisor with multiplicity $2$, and the strict transform is the normal curve $v^2-f(x)=0$.
Therefore, as Cranium Clamp tell us, we have a normal curve $v^2-f(x)=0$, with natural map to the original curve given by $(x,v)\mapsto (x,xv)$.

Thank you, what does make you say that in the first case we need two blowups and the second just one blow-up? Isn't a blow-up in this case "just" replacing the double point by a $\mathbb{P}^1$? Is there a place where I can read about these blow-ups?

Hi, in Hartshorne for example you can read about blow-up on the plane in at point, and  as you said we have replaced the singularity by a $\mathbb{P}^1$, it is $x=0$, the exceptional divisor $E$. In the second case we obtain a smooth curve, in the first we obtain an intersection between $E$ and the strict transform of the curve of a single point of higher multiplicity. You can check it by reading Hartshorne or The red book of schemes and varieties. :)

Great, many thanks for the explanation and the references ;)
